# acl.allow not working in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, acl

When I am trying to apply some authentication in `.hg/hgrc` file on Ubuntu machine its not working.

I have added below code to `hgrc` file on Ubuntu

```
[web]
allow_push=*
allow_read=*
push_ssl =false

[hooks]
pretxnchangegroup.acl=python:hgext.acl.hook

[acl.allow]
/home/test/testrepository/*=myid
```

When I am pushing some data from my Windows repository to testrepository on Ubuntu giving below message

```
pushing to http://ubantuip:8000
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
remote: error: pretxnchangegroup.acl hook failed: acl: access denied for changes
et 69f00e372c67
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
remote: abort: acl: access denied for changeset 69f00e372c67
```

why I am not able to push the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths in the `[acl.allow]` are relative to the root of the repository. They are meant to be used like this where you give "myid" access to the files under the `doc` repository:

```
[acl.allow]
doc/** = myid
```

You have used an absolute path in your config file.

Comment: thanks for your reply but its still not working same error is there

Comment: i was also thinking about path but i tried almost everything in path but not working..does any one has working example of path for ubuntu...or as my mercurain version on ubutu is 1.4.3 and on windows its 1.7.3 is it the reason for error?

Comment: Current packages are available for Ubuntu as well: https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases